# Ignored blend weights in exported FBX file

Tags: animation, export, rigging

I have made a simple rig for a model I have, where some vertices are not affected by any bone. When I export this model as an FBX file, blend weights and indices are ignored for vertices that are not affected by any bone. The encoder for proprietary format for the game engine I'm using gets upset by not all vertices having the same set of data.

Is there a way to force Blender to include zero blend weights and indices and not ignore them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you find that there is no user-based solution; you could try and prove this is not normal by using a trial application that has better support for FBX and test the combination there.  Now file a detailed bug report that logs everything you know about the problem.  Now that I think of it, you should start a blog immediately and detail everything you do since every clue will help.  FBX is closed source which means that it has to be reverse engineered.  The more help a person has with that, the better it will go.